# Any way to use N-channel mosfet in P-channel configuration?

Tags: microcontroller, transistors, mosfet

In my application, I need the HIGH signal to turn a device OFF and vice versa. Clearly, this is P-mosfet configuration. However, I only N-mosfet on hand.
Is there any clever way to utilize N-mosfet to turn a device OFF when signal is HIGH ?
In other words, given a switch (N-channel mosfet) , is there any way to turn a motor ON when signal is LOW & vice versa ?

[image: Credit:vishay.com]

Credit:vishay.com

Comment: Talking about "the ON signal" makes no sense.  A signal can have different levels which might indicate on or off, but there is no universaly standard for what "on" is.

Comment: We use High/Low then

Answer (score 6):

As Olin says, the definition of ON can mean a few things - for instance, do you mean current flowing from drain to source? Or a "high" voltage at the drain in a common source setup?

If you mean a way of switching an N-ch MOSFET off when a positive voltage relative to the source is applied to the gate, the answer is no, there is nothing "clever" that can be done.

However, there are a couple of options depending on what it is you need to do:

If it's a voltage signal you want to drive a load (.e. current gain needed), a simple way to achieve this would be to put another N-ch common drain MOSFET in front of it to invert the signal, for example something like this:

[image: Inverting MOSFET]

If the current gain is unimportant, but you wish to switch a larger voltage, then a [common gate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_gate) setup could be used:

[image: Common gate MOSFET]

Simulation:

[image: Common Gate MOSFET Simulation]

Comment: Yes, first example is a good one !

Answer (score 0):

Sadly no as it seems you are using an enhancement mode NMOS.

```
Potential solutions:
1.Use a depletion mode NMOS
2.Use a second nmos to create a not gate (or just use a not gate if you have one)
3.Use a PMOS as you yourself suggested (probably will be trickier because of the body diode)
```

Answer (score 0):

The diagrams mentioned by other answers on this page where a resistor is used can distort your signal significantly.  The resistor will slow down the charging rate of the FET gates which will smooth out the leading edge of your inverted signal. Using an actual inverter or 555 inverter "squares up" the wave to keep nice sharp/hard edges.

A solution worth mentioning is to use the trusty workhorse 555 IC as an Inverter.  Go to the bottom of this page to see the 555 wired as an inverter:

http://electronicsclub.info/555timer.htm